# Solving this differential equation on the unit interval?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \left\{0 \right\}$ and let $g$ be a $C^{1}$ function from $[0,1]$ to $ \mathbb{C}$. So $g$ has a derivative and that derivative is continuous. Let $f \in L^2 ([0,1])$. I wish to solve the differential equation $$ - \lambda f^{'} (x) + f(x) = g^{'} (x)$$ for $f$ explicitly.

I know the solution of the homogeneous equation is $$ f(x) = K \exp(x/ \lambda)$$ for some constant $K$. However, how to find a particular solution? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Look for particular solution by variating the constant $K$.

Comment: What do you mean?